# Write Multiple CSV files in a loop

Tags: r, csv, xls

I have a csv file with 1.5 million rows which consists of 2 columns name and email.I want to write a program in such way that when I read my file in R, the output is  segmented of 5000 data in each csv.

Maybe I can do this with a loop: run from row 1 to 5000 and save it as project1.csv and then 5001 to 10000 and save to project2.csv and then 10001 till 15000 in project3.csv in my working directory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that 'df1' is the `data.frame` which we need to segment every 5000 rows and save it in a new file, we `split` the dataset by creating a grouping index based on the sequence of rows to a `list` (`lst`).  We loop through the sequence of `list` elements (`lapply(...`), and write new file with `write.csv`.

```
n <- 5000
lst <-  split(df1, ((seq_len(nrow(df1)))-1)%/%n+1L)
invisible(lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) 
   write.csv(lst[[i]], file=paste0('project', i, '.csv'), row.names=FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thanks and awesome its worked ...u saved my day almost

Comment: what if i have 7 columns instead of 2

Comment: @Sandy2511  It should be the same code as the split is dependent upon the rows and not the columns.

Answer (score 0):

An answer using `purrr` and `readr`

```
n <- 5000
split(df1, ((seq_len(nrow(df1)))-1)%/%n+1L) %>%
  purrr::iwalk(., ~ readr::write_csv(.x, paste0("project", .y, ".csv")))
```