# Write multiple data frames to csv-file using purrr::map

Tags: r, csv, purrr

PROBLEM:

I have a list of dataframes which should be written to disk as csv-files.

Assume this is the list of data frames:

```
dfs <- list(iris,
            mtcars)
```

WHAT DID NOT WORK:

I have tried to build the correct file names like this, but it did not work:

```
dfs %>% 
  map(~paste0("data-raw/", ., ".csv"))
```

I hoped that this bit would correctly give back the file names as strings. Instead, `map` matched each column and each value to the `paste0` call.

I also tried the `deparse(substitute(.))` trick, but the `.` was not reckognized correctly in the `map` call.

The next step would be to write the data frames (elements of `dfs`) as csv-files.

QUESTION:

How can I use `purrr::map`(or a similar appraoch) to write each data frame (each element of `dfs`) as csv-file to disk using `write_csv`?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898812/r-read-and-write-multiple-csv-in-a-loop). Since the answer was not accepted I cannot mark your Q as duplicate. Please check the answer that hopefully provides an answer to you, and upvote it afterwards so I mark your question. In case it does not work, I can still support you. Also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054315/write-multiple-csv-files-in-a-loop) might be interseting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the support. This partially works: `lapply(seq_along(dfs), function(i) paste0("data-raw/", i, ".csv"))`
- but I need files such as `mtcars.csv`, rather than `1.csv` which is given back by this call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`map()` and `walk()` both work, but `walk()` doesn't print anything, whereas `map()` will.

Invisible output

```
list(iris = iris, mtcars = mtcars) %>%
  names(.) %>%
  walk(~ write_csv(dfs[[.]], paste0("data-raw/", ., ".csv")))
```

Prints output to console

```
list(iris = iris, mtcars = mtcars) %>%
  names(.) %>%
  map(~ write_csv(dfs[[.]], paste0("data-raw/", ., ".csv")))
```