# Error write_csv thinks data.frame isn't TRUE, write.csv does

Tags: r, readr

I'm trying to write out a .csv file.

`readr::write_csv` seems to think that my file isn't a `data.frame`.

When I run:

```
PriceCostRaw <- write_csv(PriceCostRaw, "Price Cost Raw.csv")
```

it returns this error:

```
Error in write_delim(x, path, delim = ",", na = na, append = append, 
col_names = col_names) : 
is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE
```

It is in fact a `data.frame`:

```
> str(PriceCostRaw)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   192 obs. of  7 variables:

> is.data.frame(PriceCostRaw)
[1] TRUE
```

`utils::write.csv` seems to work just fine.

Why is this happening with `write_csv`?  Are there other tests I can check for to make sure something weird is going on with my data file or variable structures?

I can't post the data itself because it's proprietary.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, all I can suggest is to make sure you have the latest versions of readr and R and to try again in a clean session.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: try `write_excel_csv`.

Comment: I had already checked that it was current versions of both readr and R, and I had already restarted my R session.  I restarted the session again, reinstalled readr (with the same version number), and it worked this time.  Strange.  Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducing the `write_delim() ... is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE` issue on my system:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrrlyr)
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    nest() %>%
    by_row(~write_csv(.$data, 
                      path = file.path(tempdir(), paste0(.$Species, ".csv"))))
# Error in write_delim(x, path, delim = ",", na = na, append = append,
#                      col_names = col_names,  : 
# is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE
```

There probably is a simpler way, I was trying to write a data frame to many csv files. Inspired by an answer to this Stackoverflow question: 
[Write multiple data frames to csv-file using purrr::map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529149/2641825)

The code does work when replacing `write_csv()` with the base R version `write.csv()`:

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    nest() %>%
    by_row(~write.csv(.$data, 
                      file = file.path(tempdir(), paste0(.$Species, ".csv"))))
```

Successfully writes many csv files, each with a species name.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly specify `path = ...` in `write_csv()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `write_csv`, you should make sure that your input is a dataframe. You could use `as.data.frame` like this (mtcars dataset as an example):

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  dplyr::group_walk(~ write_csv(.x$data, paste0(.y$cyl, ".csv")))
#> Error in write_delim(x, file, delim = ",", na = na, append = append, col_names = col_names, : is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  dplyr::group_walk(~ write_csv(as.data.frame(.x$data), paste0(.y$cyl, ".csv")))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, the error is gone when using `as.data.frame`.

Comment: Shouldn't it also work with a tibble? According to the documentation x can be "A data frame or tibble to write to disk."  https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/write_delim.html